# What will I need to do before building the rocket silo?

Tags: factorio

This is my first free-play game of Factorio.  I've built a bunch of technologies, and I'm starting to think about what I'll need to build the rocket silo.  It looks like I'm going to need a whole bunch of basic resources, plus a few hundred alien artifact orbs.

Question: is it going to be necessary for me to build a railway in order to get enough resources to build the rocket pod?  Can I fudge it with, y'know, a few mining bases and a long conveyor belt, or will I be collecting resources from all over the map?-

<strike>Question: what is necessary to get a few hundred alien artifact orbs?  Can I do this with leapfrogging laser turrets, or do I need to research the power armor II and get a bunch of capsules?  How many alien bases will I need to clean out to get this many orbs?</strike> **EDIT**: Alien artifacts no longer exist as of 0.15

Comment: You should separate these questions since they are really different.

Comment: The second part of the question is no longer applicable, as artifacts were removed from the game in 0.15

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happened:

- No, it was not necessary to build a railway to launch the rocket. My copper did run out at one point, so I built a copper mining outpost and hooked it up to my base with conveyor belts. My iron never ran out.
- No, it was not necessary to research or build guns or power armor. I cleared out some nearby bases with laser turrets -- basically, I killed the ones that seemed likely to smell my pollution and attack -- and that was more than sufficient to research the rocket. I didn't get a close look at the aliens because my turrets mostly killed them when they were off screen, but it didn't look like they had evolved significantly.